# How to detect j2me mobile device screen orientation at LWUIT?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I want to know how to detect screen orientation like portrait or landscape mode at J2ME LWUIT. Can LWUIT detect screen orientation automatically or need to write code manually?

Answer (score 2):

Shai Almog said this in the forum, talking about screen orientation

Shai Almog said...

We don't explicitly support orientation, the phone sends an event of screen size change and it supports orientation for us. we know the size has changed but we don't know the orientation has changed. 
The developer can't control orientation changes since this is done automatically based on events to the canvas.
http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2008/05/new-video-from-chen-of-lwuit-on-devices.html

I think it can help you. I am developing an app with LWUIT now, using the LWUIT resource editor, and the screen orientation is detected automatically. Anyway you must look for Display in API http://lwuit.java.net/nonav/iodocs/index.html, there are some methods that you can use for the orientation, like `Display.canForceOrientation()` or `Display.lockOrientation()`.

Comment: The lockOrientation method will only work on devices like Android/RIM, never on J2ME devices. Generally LWUIT works pretty seamlessly with orientation changes based on layout managers settings. Check out our demos on the devices and look at our code, there are plenty of examples there.

Answer (score 0):

What about `Display.getInstance().isPortrait()`